# How to rate off-topic comments in comment evaluator?

Tags: support, comments

I opened the comment evaluator today and the very first comment was:

> Have you had a solution already? I'm facing the same case as yours.

This is clearly not a "fine" comment, since it's unwanted (comments can be flagged for being "I'm having the same question" comments). However, it's also not "disrespectful or unfriendly" or even "abusive or harassment". So what do I click? None of the options fit.

Comment: Blog: [Classifying Comments](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/07/10/welcome-wagon-classifying-comments-on-stack-overflow/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sole goal of the comment evaluator is to judge whether comments are unwelcoming or not. As such, relevance or being chatty aren't what we're looking for.

If a comment isn't rude or abusive or otherwise unfriendly, mark it as "fine". I know that, as someone who removes many obsolete comments, mentally adjusting to this was a challenge for me too. Keeping in mind the goal of the evaluator, though, helped me adjust to it.

Comment: So, rate them as "fine" and flag as "It's no longer needed." to get it in the appropriate moderator queue?

Comment: There's no link from the evaluator to the site, so hunting it up on SO to flag it would take some work.